# How to locate the xml node correctly if it has same node name for many entries?

Tags: xml, powershell, xml-parsing, powershell-2.0

I am having a xml file similar to below.

```
<Parameters>
  <Parameter IsEncrypted="False">
    <ParameterName>pRdGpInstallOptions</ParameterName>
    <ParameterValue>Custom</ParameterValue>
  </Parameter>
  <Parameter IsEncrypted="False">
    <ParameterName>pRdAccept</ParameterName>
    <ParameterValue>true</ParameterValue>
  </Parameter>
  <Parameter IsEncrypted="False">
    <ParameterName>pCboEditSQLServer</ParameterName>
    <ParameterValue>MachineName\SQLEXPRESS</ParameterValue>
  </Parameter>
</Parameters>
```

I have copied only few nodes here. Actually the real file may be having hundreds of Parameter nodes.

We can't hard code the index as it may appear in any order. I am trying to retrieve SQLinstance name parameter value which is associated with Parameter Name `"pCboEditSQLServer"`.

I would like to retrieve this value using powershell. How to parse this dynamic xml files?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
$sql = $xml.Parameters.Parameter | Where-Object {$_.ParameterName -eq 'pCboEditSQLServer'}
$sql.ParameterValue

MachineName\SQLEXPRESS
```

Here's another option (should be faster) using xpath:

```
$path = "/Parameters/Parameter[ParameterName='pCboEditSQLServer']/ParameterValue"
$xml.SelectSingleNode($path).'#text'
```

And there's the `Select-Xml` cmdlet:

```
$sql = $xml | Select-Xml -XPath $path 
$sql.Node.'#text'
```

Answer (score 3):

Read XML:

`$xml = [xml](gc test.xml -Encoding utf8)`

And use object model to retrieve data:

`$xml.Parameters.Parameter | ? { $_.ParameterName -eq "pCboEditSQLServer" } | Select-Object -Property  ParameterName, ParameterValue`